# Administrator permissions in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I want to access everything in my windows 8 pc but in some files in system32 I don't have the permission to make any changes to it and I am unable to give the permission though i am the only administrator and single user of my PC. Please help me out, it would be very grateful of you.

Comment: By default you ( as an Administrator ) should be able to write to System32, it might ask for elevated permissions, but you can write to it.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to make your changes? Using Explorer or command line?

If the latter, try starting the shell with elevated rights: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/elevated-command-prompt-windows-8.htm

Comment: No i just don't want to open cmd as an admin. I want to make changes in the files like Os:c>Windows>system32>drivers>en>hosts but when i make the change it says i dont have permission adnd in previous version of windows i did it by editing the properties of the drivers folder and gave myself the permission but in W8 i am unable to do this

Comment: You do have access. You can open CMD as admin. Simply by right clicking on CMD and "Run as Administrator". If you open say using the example you provided the "hosts" file using Notepad, by default the Notepad are not under admin power, hence why you can't "save" into that folder. You can save into a different folder (eg. Desktop), and then move the file from Desktop to that location. It will prompt you for elevated permission, but you can do it. If you want to edit the file using notepad and save directly, you must run Notepad as Administrator and then you can save directly.